# Why does TS thinks `setValue` might be a `boolean`?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

Why does TS thinks `setOpen`  might be a `boolean`??

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function useLocalStorage<T> (key: string, initialValue: T) {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(() => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key)
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return initialValue
    }
  })

  const setValue = (value: T) => {
    try {
      setStoredValue(value)
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return [storedValue, setValue]
}

const [open, setOpen] = useLocalStorage('someKey', false)
console.log(open);
setOpen(true) // setOpen: boolean | (value: boolean) => void
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't declare the return type of `useLocalStorage` by default it infers an array of union types, i.e. `(boolean | (value: boolean) => void)[]` instead of a tuple `[boolean, (value: boolean) => void]`.

Declare the return type of your function:

```
export default function useLocalStorage<T> (key: string, initialValue: T): [boolean, (value: boolean) => void] {
  ...
```

There's another less obvious problem with your code though, which is that `setValue` is not properly memoized. [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) would be better suited for this:

```
export default function useLocalStorage<T> (key: string, initialValue: T) {
  return useReducer((prev: T, next: T) => {
    try {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(next))
      return next
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return prev
    }
  }, initialValue, () => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key)
      return item === null ? initialValue : JSON.parse(item)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return initialValue
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: but the returned storedValue, setValue have proper typing. Typescript is always picking this up properly. Why doesn't it pick up returned typing now?

Comment: @stkvtflw I explained why. When you return an array literal from a function, its type is inferred as an array of unions rather than a tuple of individually typed elements.

Comment: why useReducer is better? I don't have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values and the next state doesn't depend on the previous one

Comment: @stkvtflw because when `setValue` is used as a dependency for other hooks such as `useEffect()`, `useMemo()`, `useCallback()`, etc. the memoization will allow React to skip unnecessary computations and effects, whereas with your previous approach it would not skip them when passing `setValue` as a dependency.

Comment: Another solution for initial question is to do `return [storedValue, setValue] as const` - in this case TypeScript will infer the return type properly, as tuple.

Comment: @Cerberus, yes, though that additionally marks each element of the tuple as `readonly`, so it doesn't have the same semantics.

Comment: Well, the data returned from hook isn't really intended to be mutable anyway, AFAIK.